# What does the below statement mean?

Tags: relationships, data-model

I'm new here and currently i'm going through Salesforce tutorials. I found a statement as below:

> Multilevel master-detail relationships do not support division transfers.

Can anybody make me understand what does it mean?

Comment: If you are not getting the above statement, please check [This link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm) for detailed information. In that page heading "Master-Detail Relationships",  7th paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Divisions let you segment your organization's data into logical
>   sections, making searches, reports, and list views more meaningful to
>   users. For example, you can create a report to show the opportunities
>   for just the North American division, allowing you to get accurate
>   sales numbers for the North American sales team. Divisions are useful
>   for organizations with extremely large amounts of data.

Where is "Division" in Salesforce? How do I find? See [Setting Division](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=getting_started_with_divisions.htm&language=en_US)

So, statement says that when you have multilevel master relationship it won't allow you to change/transfer division for custom objects. Otherwise divisions can be changed easily.